# What is gbp.conf in debian/directory in a package

Tags: debian, debian-policy

I heard yesterday about `gbp.conf and` while installing widelands, and I came across the following:

https://tracker.debian.org/news/986137/accepted-widelands-119repack-5-source-into-unstable/

```
widelands (1:19+repack-5) unstable; urgency=medium

  [ Jeremy Bicha ]
  * Team upload.
  * Use hicolor theme icon for .desktop (Closes: #857644) (LP: #1789023)
  * Add minimal debian/gbp.conf
```

Then I looked into [debian-policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/) in the hopes that it may shed some light on this `gbp.conf`, but it didn't. I Just used find but couldn't find anything about `gbp.conf` anywhere in the policy document.

Would you please let me know what it's used for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gbp.conf` is the configuration file for `git-buildpackage`; it is documented in [its own manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/gbp.conf.5).

The configuration added to the `widelands` package is indeed [minimal](https://salsa.debian.org/games-team/widelands/blob/master/debian/gbp.conf) (not that it needs to be anything else):

```
[DEFAULT]
pristine-tar = True
```

This configures all `gbp-buildpackage` actions to use `pristine-tar`.